# Stop a Twisted Fiber Mid-Execution

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, fiber

There are many ways to create a Python Twisted fiber.  For example, one could call `reactor.callWhenRunning(helloWorld)`.  `helloWorld()` will execute and the fiber will stop executing when `helloWorld()` returns.

What if half way through executing `helloWorld()` I wanted to stop the fiber's execution without impacting the rest of the fibers?  How would I do that?

If the execution is inside `helloWorld()` itself, then I could simply return from the method.  But, what if the program is 10 nested calls deep?  How would I stop the fiber's execution from continuing?  I suppose I could make all 10 methods return immediately but that would be very difficult to code for a large program with 1000s of methods.

I could raise an exception.  This would work unless some method in the call stack (besides the reactor) catches the exception.

I could do the following.  However, this will add a lot of pending `Deferred`s to pile up in the Twisted reactor.

```
while True:
    d       = defer.Deferred()
    d.delay = reactor.callLater(sys.maxint, d.callback, None)

    yield d
```

Are there any other solutions?

Note:  A Python 2.6 solution would be ideal.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no such thing as a "fiber" in Twisted.  Fibers are a cooperative threading library for Windows - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - and Twisted doesn't work in a similar way.

Comment: I haven't been sure about what to call what Twisted does.  That's why I put fiber in quotes.  However, after reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29, it seems that fiber is the right word.  It you have a better word, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply call `cancel()` on the Deferred before `yield`ing.  The code does not continue execution after the `yield`.

```
d       = defer.Deferred()
d.delay = reactor.callLater(sleepTime, d.callback, None)

d.cancel()

yield d
returnValue(None)
```